# Unable to generate references for document while using elsarticle class

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I have tried a lot to generate reference for my document using the `elsarticle` class for submission in Elsevier publications. But I don't know where I am making a mistake in getting the bibliography. Below I attach the code I used:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{}
\author{}
\address{}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
\label{}
    Several researchers studied ruin probability, but for a survey
see\cite{conner2014making}. For bulk arrival queues see
\cite{frazier2014metal}
\section{\refname}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{trialreferences}
\end{document}
```

and here is my bibliography file;

```
@article{conner2014making,
  title={Making sense of 3-D printing: Creating a map of additive manufacturing products and services},
  author={Conner, Brett P and Manogharan, Guha P and Martof, Ashley N and Rodomsky, Lauren M and Rodomsky, Caitlyn M and Jordan, Dakesha C and Limperos, James W},
  journal={Additive Manufacturing},
  volume={1},
  pages={64--76},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{frazier2014metal,
    title={Metal additive manufacturing: a review},
    author={Frazier, William E},
    journal={Journal of Materials Engineering and Performance},
    volume={23},
    number={6},
    pages={1917--1928},
    year={2014},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Welcome,  are you getting question marks instead of the number you expect?

Comment: Do you run pdfLaTeX + bibTeX + pdfLaTeX twice?

Comment: Do you have `model1a-num-names.bst`? It was not on my machine and I had to google it. I took the first link and downloaded the file, but that did not look like an official Elsevier link. https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions only links to CTAN where the standard `elsarticle-num-names.bst` can be found.

Comment: Johannes_B:  yes, i am getting question marks instead of the numbers

Comment: @RockyRock: yes i have run it twice. still the question mark persists

Comment: You not only have to run LaTeX twice. You also need to run BibTeX. Do you get any errors or warning when you run BibTeX? (Either on the terminal or in the `.blg` file). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: @moewe: yeah, i am using texstudio and the ordered list of commands in Texstudio is pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex. It runs without errors and i have tried with elsarticle-num-names too. Still it doesn't take the references.

Comment: Mhhh, if you get question marks even after running that sequence, something must be wrong. And if something is wrong, there must be errors or warnings. Please check the `.blg` file directly, don't rely on the digest produced by TeXstudio.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks moewe. I think elsarticle-num-names bibliographystyle hve worked after i have run the ordered list of commands twice or thrice. Thank you very much